# Stored procedure will not insert

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am working on a Javascript stored procedure that selects data from a group of tables and inserts into a target table I called forecast.

I have added comments to my code for ease of comprehension.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE forecast(SITE_ID VARCHAR, PCT FLOAT, PRODUCT VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR NOT NULL
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
COMMENT = 'abc'
AS
$$
var sql = `WITH FINAL AS (
...
WHERE (site_id = :1)
),
future as (
select 
...
union all
select 
...
) 
SELECT
:2,
sce.site_id,
sce.subscription_id,
sce.receiver_contact,
sce.subscription_status,
sce.change_mrr_event_type,
sce.modification_time,
sce.churn_type,
sce.mrr,
sce.product_name,
sce.country_name,
sce.segment,
sce.source_name,
sce.mrr_change
from future as sce
...`;

try {
    //main vars for input parameters
    var single_quote="'";
    var Product_In = PRODUCT;
    var MRR_In = PCT;
    // we capture the most recent value of the model sequence number in the target table
    var sql_command = "select ifnull(max(model_seq),0) as model_seq from forecast";
    var stmt1 = snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: sql_command });
    var resultSet1 = stmt1.execute();
    resultSet1.next();

    // we increment above value by 1 before going to work
    var MODEL_SEQ = resultSet1.getColumnValue(1);
    MODEL_SEQ++;

    // we execute the copy 
    var stmt2 = snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: sql, binds: [SITE_ID, MODEL_SEQ, PCT, PRODUCT] });
    var resultSet2 = stmt2.execute();
    resultSet2.next();
    // and scroll the cursor/resultset
    // insert into the target table when true
    for (i = 1; i <= resultSet2.getRowCount(); i++) {
        SITE_ID = resultSet2.getColumnValue(2)
        SUBSCRIPTION_ID = resultSet2.getColumnValue(3)
        RECEIVER_CONTACT = resultSet2.getColumnValue(4)
        SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS = resultSet2.getColumnValue(5)
        CHANGE_MRR_EVENT_TYPE = resultSet2.getColumnValue(6)
        MODIFICATION_TIME = resultSet2.getColumnValue(7)
        CHURN_TYPE = resultSet2.getColumnValue(8)
        MRR = resultSet2.getColumnValue(9)
        PRODUCT_NAME = resultSet2.getColumnValue(10)
        COUNTRY_NAME = resultSet2.getColumnValue(11)
        SEGMENT = resultSet2.getColumnValue(12)
        SOURCE_NAME = resultSet2.getColumnValue(13)
        MRR_CHANGE = resultSet2.getColumnValue(14)

        //We check for a specific condition - if true, we process MRR
        if (CHANGE_MRR_EVENT_TYPE === 'Activation' && PRODUCT_NAME === single_quote+Product_In+single_quote)
        {
            //if true, we process MRR
            MRR_Out = (MRR + (MRR * MRR_In / 100))
            //Position based binding
            var sql_insert = "INSERT INTO FORECAST VALUES (:1, :2, :3, :4, :5, :6, :7, :8, :9, :10, :11, :12, :13, :14)";
            var stmt3 = snowflake.createStatement(
                {
                    sqlText: sql_insert,
                    binds: [MODEL_SEQ, SITE_ID, SUBSCRIPTION_ID, RECEIVER_CONTACT, SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS, CHANGE_MRR_EVENT_TYPE, MODIFICATION_TIME, CHURN_TYPE, MRR_Out, PRODUCT_NAME, COUNTRY_NAME, SEGMENT, SOURCE_NAME, MRR_CHANGE]
                }   
            );
            //insert this row
            var resultSet3 = stmt3.execute();
            resultSet3.next();  
            //next row in source data cursor
            resultSet2.next();

        }
    }

    result = "Succeeded";
}
catch (err) {
    result = "Failed: Code: " + err.code + "\n  State: " + err.state;
    result += "\n  Message: " + err.message;
    result += "\nStack Trace:\n" + err.stackTraceTxt;
}
return result;
$$
;
```

Looking at the data for `stmt2`, I can return anything I want e.g. `CHANGE_MRR_EVENT_TYPE` or even `PRODUCT_NAME` so I know that part is working as intended. However, the INSERT simply never happens. No errors, nothing.

I believe there's an issue with the way I am binding the variables but I cannot see what it is. Any pointers?

Comment: This seems as it is written to be a INSERT from SELECT which has two WHERE clauses, that you are doing in a LOOP instead of as a single READ/WRITE, is there a reason for this?

Comment: It is an INSERT from SELECT, correct. That's the requirement I was instructed to follow.

Comment: you can write `INSERT INTO tablename(columns) SELECT...`  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/insert#multi-row-insert-using-query which does one READ and one WRITE operation, as compared to many WRITES

Comment: I know it does but this is not what I want to do. I need to select data from my source tables, look at each row and each if it matches a criteria, process it if it does and insert it. `INSERT ... SELECT` won't help me here. It is more than just a bulk insert but a cursor that I have to iterate over.

Comment: I thought MMR_Out was a rolling sum, it is not. so never mind..

Comment: I guess the heart of what I am saying is, you should try VERY hard to turn it into a single READ/WRITE and if you need to carry state like a rolling sum, and other things, get that working in a SELECT, so you can get the data you care about, and then turn that into a single INSERT/SELECT pattern verse doing custom logic in the stored proc. having processed petabytes of data the way I describe, it is much faster to think how the DB likes to think,

Answer (score 0):

This SQL is doing nothing special, and thus could just be a simple two phase call, as the first is to get the `MODEL_SEQ`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE forecast(SITE_ID VARCHAR, PCT FLOAT, PRODUCT VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR NOT NULL
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
COMMENT = 'abc'
AS
$$
var sql = `
INSERT INTO FORECAST
    WITH FINAL AS (
        ...
        WHERE (site_id = :1)
    ), future as (
        select 
        ...
        union all
        select 
        ...
    ) 
    SELECT
        :2,
        sce.site_id,
        sce.subscription_id,
        sce.receiver_contact,
        sce.subscription_status,
        sce.change_mrr_event_type,
        sce.modification_time,
        sce.churn_type,
        sce.mrr + (sce.mrr * :3 / 100.0),
        sce.product_name,
        sce.country_name,
        sce.segment,
        sce.source_name,
        sce.mrr_change
    from future as sce
    ...
    WHERE sce.change_mrr_event_type = 'Activation' AND sce.product_name = :5
    `;

try {
    //main vars for input parameters
    var single_quote="'";
    var quoted_product_in = single_quote + PRODUCT + single_quote;
    
    // we capture the most recent value of the model sequence number in the target table
    var sql_command = "select ifnull(max(model_seq),0) as model_seq from forecast";
    
    var stmt1 = snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: sql_command });
    var resultSet1 = stmt1.execute();
    resultSet1.next();

    // we increment above value by 1 before going to work
    var MODEL_SEQ = resultSet1.getColumnValue(1);
    MODEL_SEQ++;

    // we execute the copy 
    var stmt2 = snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: sql, binds: [SITE_ID, MODEL_SEQ, PCT, PRODUCT, quoted_product_in] });
    
    var resultSet2 = stmt2.execute();
    resultSet2.next();
    
    result = "Succeeded";
}
catch (err) {
    result = "Failed: Code: " + err.code + "\n  State: " + err.state;
    result += "\n  Message: " + err.message;
    result += "\nStack Trace:\n" + err.stackTraceTxt;
}
return result;
$$
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the INSERT statement inside the IF clause was not running, I rewrote it thusly

```
...
        if (CHANGE_MRR_EVENT_TYPE === 'Activation' && PRODUCT_NAME === Product_In) 
        {
            //since we change MRR, we change MRR_CHANGE as well?
            MRR_Out = (MRR + (MRR * MRR_In / 100))
            //Position based binding    
            var sql_insert = "INSERT INTO FORECAST VALUES (:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6,:7,:8,:9,:10,:11,:12,:13,:14)";
            var stmt3 = snowflake.execute(
                {
                    sqlText: sql_insert,
                    binds: [MODEL_SEQ, SITE_ID, SUBSCRIPTION_ID, RECEIVER_CONTACT, SUBSCRIPTION_STATUS, CHANGE_MRR_EVENT_TYPE, MODIFICATION_TIME, CHURN_TYPE, MRR_Out, PRODUCT_NAME, COUNTRY_NAME, SEGMENT, SOURCE_NAME, MRR_CHANGE]
                }
            );
        }
        //next row in source data
        resultSet2.next();
...
```

I simply changed the signature from `createStatement` followed by `execute` to just using `execute`. I didn't change anything else in the code.